# short circuit current battery

Tags: battery-operated, batteries

I am working with a zinc air battery. When I short circuit my battery with a wire and record the voltage at the battery, my voltage is decreasing until 0 mV. Can I say that my battery is dead ? In other words, is a short circuit current equal to zero equivalent to a dead battery ?

Answer (score 2):

Well there is an effect of relaxation in the battery. So after you remove the short circuit and let the battery sit for a while (30 minutes or something) it might build up some voltage again and you might squeeze out some more coulombs. I don't know how strong this effect is in zinc-air chemistries.

But when the short circuit was long enough for the current to drop to zero, your battery won't relax much and you basically killed it.

Comment: thanks! but where comes from this relaxation effect ?

Comment: @velleda good question but I don't know. I just know it exists at least in lithium based chemistries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is dead, or actually ' used up' ... by shortcutting all energy will flow from the plus to minus (or actually electrons from minus to plus) and all 'energy' is used.